# How long are mining rewards locked on testnet?

Tags: testnet, transaction-unlock-time, block-reward, mining

I started a Monero testnet daemon this morning, and started mining to get a few testnet coins. Meanwhile, after mining 13 blocks, my wallet says:

`Balance: 167.583046443332, unlocked balance: 0.000000000000`

However, they're all still locked. The oldest block I mined is already ± 40 blocks ago. Is there a longer lock time for testnet? Or is this always the case (mainnet and testnet) for coinbase transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rules are the same as on the main network, you need to wait 60 blocks (ca. 2 hours) to see the balance unlocked for coins that you mine.

For normal transactions, the balance is locked for 10 blocks only (ca. 20 minutes).

Comment: Thanks, correct. For regular (non-coinbase) transactions it is less than 60 blocks, right?

Comment: Yes, for normal transactions it's only 10 blocks (~ 20 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Now, at `bc_height` 838829, I am seeing an unlocked balance for my first 3 blocks:

```
Balance: 335.155028799342, unlocked balance: 38.674047189118
[wallet 9u7fCD]: show_transfers in
  838765     in      06:55:30 AM      12.891381847472
  838766     in      06:56:12 AM      12.891357259112
  838768     in      06:57:30 AM      12.891308082534
  838773     in      07:13:27 AM      12.891185141908
[wallet 9u7fCD]: bc_height
838829
```

The difference between 838829 and 838768 is 61 blocks. So, I am guessing that the lock time is probably 60 blocks?